# How to change the button position on materialize?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have this situation:

```
<div class="col s12 m3 center-align">
            <ul class="personal_info">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons icn_profile small">mail</i></a></li>
              <li style="margin-bottom:5px"><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin icn_profile small" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li><a id="phone" class="tooltipped" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="00000" data-position="right"><i class="material-icons icn_profile small waves-effect">phone</i></a></li>
              <li style="margin-top:15px">
                <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle">
                  <a class="btn-floating btn">
                    <i class="small material-icons">language</i>
                  </a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a class="btn-floating btn">Ita</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn-floating btn">Esp</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

When I click to the floating button the related buttons appears at the top right corner of the page, how can I change this behavior?

I want the buttons to stay near the toggle button, in the horizontal position. Like showed in the materialize doc (Horizontal fab)

The only change I did is this:

```
.fixed-action-btn.horizontal{
  position: static;
}
```

Now the main button appears where I want, but, when I click on it, the others stay not close to him.

Comment: make your code available online.

Comment: i cannot at the moment, i update the question